# TF.MultiHeadAttention with 1D Data and Ghost Dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, transformer-model

Background:
My data has shape of (batch_size, data_length) and the dimensions seem to be incompatible with the inside MultiHeadAttention operations, especially softmax. Someone kindly suggested that I should use a size 1 ghost dimension as the last dimension.

Error message I got:

```
(32, 512, 1)
Epoch 1/200

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-7-870abeaa4b93> in <cell line: 281>()
    279 model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="rmsprop", metrics=["accuracy"])
    280 
--> 281 history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=200, validation_data=val_dataset)

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1050, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'query' (type EinsumDense).
    
    Dimensions must be equal, but are 1 and 512 for '{{node model/multi_head_attention/query/einsum/Einsum}} = Einsum[N=2, T=DT_HALF, equation="abc,cde->abde"](model/Cast, model/multi_head_attention/query/einsum/Einsum/Cast)' with input shapes: [32,512,1], [512,2,512].
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'query' (type EinsumDense):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(32, 512, 1), dtype=float16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message mentions an einsum "equation": "abc,cde->abde" (Numpy has a [very clear explanation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) of einsum if you aren't familiar with it). This is telling you that **this specific error** (though possibly not your original error, I can't tell) is caused because this specific step expects the last axis of the array to be the same as the first axis of the next. It also tells you it expects 3 axes in both arrays.

Your second array obviously already has 3 axes. You said you added a unit axis to your other array. This is reasonable, though it has to be put in the right place, as the second axis instead of the third: `x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, 1)`. This will make the dimensions match.

PS: You say you are giving a "Brief reproducible code". It may be brief, but it's not reproducible: you've left out the imports, you haven't provided `dataset` or `val_dataset`, you get an `IndexError` at `padding_mask_init[rows, 1:, 1] = 1` and you have a syntax error on the line `shape = (batch_size, embed_dim, ghost_dim=1)`: this isn't valid Python. Next time, in order to ensure you are actually attaching a reproducible example, create a new file (example.py), paste your code into the file, and try to run it with `python example.py`. Until this produces the error you're wanting help with, it's not a reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanations! Ps. I tried to edit the code to actually run, and give an incompatible dimensions error. My original code is something around 310 lines, so a bit challenging to briefly include here without giving people 290 irrelevant lines to read.

Comment: Update: Just had the opportunity today to try adding the ghost dim to second axis as in the answer and works beautifully! Thank you.